# can I run a selenium driver with Quarkus?

Tags: selenium, quarkus

I understand that Selenium is implemented in Java. And Quarkus is Java without some of the frameworks' intensive use of reflection. I could not find any reference of anybody launching a selenium webdriver with Quarkus.

Has this been done already?

Comment: I haven't seen anyone mention this in either the Quarkus char or Quarkus GitHub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it works as I am using it with some small adaptations, i.e. you have to exclude a conflicting transitive dependency (version), in the maven project `pom.xml` like following:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>3.141.59</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
      <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Then you can use the regular Selenium features, i.e.

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setHeadless(true); // Using a dockerized selenium
seleniumDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://selenium-chrome-standalone:4444/wd/hub"), chromeOptions);
seleniumDriver.get("http://<Quarkus service URL>");
// do some things
seleniumDriver.quit();
```

You can also start a Selenium driver service on your own (instead of a dockerized or remote one):

```
ChromeDriverService service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
    .usingDriverExecutable(new File("src/test/resources/seleniumdrivers/chromedriver_linux64_81.0.4044.138/chromedriver"))
    .usingAnyFreePort()
    .build();
service.start();
```

Or using a dockerized Selenium within `gitlab-ci.yml` like this:

```
uitest:
  stage: uitest
  services:
    - name: selenium/standalone-chrome
      alias: selenium-chrome-standalone
```

With this, I even managed to access the Quarkus service when running integration tests (`@QuarkusTest`) in the pipeline with

```
@TestHTTPResource("/myServicePath")
URL serviceResourceUrl;
```